# Why isn't the fetched record being displayed?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have this code in one file called: "edit-post.php"

```
if (isset($_GET['ide'])) {

        $id = $_GET['ide'];

        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = {$id}");
        $row = $sql->fetch_object();

        if ($sql) {
            include('view_edit-post.php');  
        } 
    }
```

And here is the code for "view_edit-post.php"

```
<div id="edit-post">
    <div id="header">
        <span class="title">Edit post</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row->title ?>"/><br/>
            <textarea name="announcement" ><?php echo $row->announcements ?></textarea><br/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect to see whatever is fetched from my sql statement(edit-post.php) to be displayed in view_edit-post.php.. However, I'm getting these errors:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$title
Undefined property: stdClass::$announcement
```

What could I've done wrong?

PS: I'm trying to figure this out for the past 2 days, tried everything,still without luck.

Comment: If it's all in one file, I don't see an element called/named "ide". How are you retrieving that from? You're using a GET and POST method, so it makes it that much more harder to tell what should be calling what. You also don't have a POST variable set for `name="announcement"` nor for `name="title"` and other elements.

Comment: @Fred -ii  Hi. The edit-post.php is included in another file which is where the ide value is being retrieved from.. Anyways, I don't think that the problem roots there.. see, when i run the code, the view_edit-post.php is being included which means that the sql statement executed successfully.

Comment: Try, `var_dump($row);`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're looping over your form (from what you posted anyway)... `while($row...` (exit PHP, enter in HTML) `<form>...</form>` re-enter PHP. That's why we need to see how your entire code looks like and not just one piece of the form, but in its actual form.